# find infimum of $(n+1)^2 / 2^n$ (using Bernoulli's inequality)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the infimum for:

$$(n+1)^2 / 2^n$$

I've tried to simplify $2^n$ with Bernoulli's inequality $((1+1)^n \ge (1+n))$
but it didn't work out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $$\frac{(n+2)^2}{2^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{2^n}{(n+1)^2} \to \frac12 < 1.$$

Comment: Didn't you mean (n+1)^2 in the left numerator?

Comment: The above expression is $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ for $a_n = \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}$.

Comment: OK, got it. but not sure how does it help me..

Comment: It implies that $\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{2^n} \to 0$, i.e. your infimum is $0$.